# Alternative to Python Pickle less sensitive to refactoring

Tags: python, pickle

This is probably a relatively common concern but I haven't found any real answer so far.

Let's use an example to illustrate why Pickle is not satisfying here: I have a file which contains a class that takes a long time (tens of hours) to instantiate. Once instantiated, I then save it to a pickle file:

```py
import pickle
import time

from foo.bar import baz

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.message = baz.very_long_computation()

obj = MyClass()

with open('./obj.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(obj)
```

From a different file in the same repository, I want to load the instantiated object and use it, without having to wait:

```py
import pickle

with open('./obj.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    obj = pickle.load(f)

print(obj.message)
```

What can happen sometimes is that I change e.g. the `baz` module's location in the folder structure (without necessarily modify its content), for instance I move it from `foo.bar.baz` to `qux.bar.baz`.

Now, if I try to load `obj.pickle` again, Python will complain with a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named foo`.

It seems that whenever I make the slightest refactoring, I have to completely re-instantiate `MyClass`, involving this long waiting time. In practice this is terribly annoying, hence my two questions:

- is there any alternative to Pickle that wouldn't force re-instantiating?
- is there a way to avoid this problem while still using Pickle?

Note: I understand that in the above example, I would simply have to save `self.message` into a text file and call it a day. In reality, it would be complex to persist the object's content in such a manner.

Comment: Can you save the internals of the object in terms of Python built-ins? Because that would be much more stable

Comment: Not in this case, no

Comment: Hmm, why not? What makes it special?

Comment: The real `MyClass` is `sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer` which has been instantiated with (among other things) a custom class located in a certain folder, and this particular path has been saved into the pickled file.

Comment: (i) Does the package `dill` help? (ii) A cheesy, unrecommendable way is to export an alias of the old module name. (iii) Or, `class bazWrapper(baz): \n   pass`, and pickle / unpickle bazWrapper?